# Gradient descent (derivative) from an algorithm to minimize the error, but doesn't work with negative real value

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, gradient-descent

Best

I've a simple algorithm and I would like to minimize its error.
Therefore I'm planning to calculate the derivatives with respect to the input.

**algorithm:**
-- constant values --
$$ real = 3 $$
-- initial parameters -- 
$$ Ain = 1.6$$
$$ Bin = -1.2$$

-- algorithm --
$$ Aout = 10^{\frac{\left | Ain \right |}{3}}-1 $$
$$ Bout = 10^{\frac{\left | Bin \right |}{3}}-1 $$ 
$$ error = (real - Aout - Bout)^{2} $$

-- derivatives -- 
$$ Aout\_der = \frac{log(10) * Ain * 10^{ \frac{|Ain|}{3} }}{3 * |Ain|}$$
$$ Bout\_der = \frac{log(10) * Bin * 10^{ \frac{|Bin|}{3} }}{3 * |Bin|}$$
$$ error\_A\_der = 2*( real - Aout - Bout ) * ( - Aout\_der ) $$ 
$$ error\_B\_der = 2*( real - Aout - Bout ) * ( - Bout\_der ) $$

Here you can see my program

## program

```
for i in range(10000):

    #-------------------#
    # STEP 1: Goad diff #
    #-------------------#
    Aout = 10^( |Ain| /3 ) - 1 
    Bout = 10^( |Bin| /3 ) - 1 

    Aout_der = ( log(10) * Ain * 10^( |Ain| /3) ) / (3 * |Ain|)
    Bout_der = ( log(10) * Bin * 10^( |Bin| /3) ) / (3 * |Bin|)

    #--------------------#
    # Step 2: Error      #
    #--------------------#-----------------#
    # |u(x)| ′  =  u(x) / |u(x)| * u'(x)   #
    # &                                    #
    # u(x)**n ′  =  n * u(x)**n−1  * u′(x) #
    #--------------------------------------#

    error = ( real - Aout - Bout )^2

    # Derivative error to Ain and Bin        
    error_A_der = 2*( real - Aout - Bout ) * ( - Aout_der )
    error_B_der = 2*( real - Aout - Bout ) * ( - Bout_der )

    #--------------------------------#
    # Step 3: update the Ain and Bin #
    #--------------------------------#
    Ain = Ain - error_A_der * 0.001
    Bin = Bin  - error_B_der * 0.001


    # stop criteria
    if error  < 0.0001:
        break
```

And everything works okey, as long as ***real > 0***

**if real = 3**

```
i stopped at: 584
error: 9.759144048796994e-09
Ain: 1.3523187418649631
Bin: -1.0133921615317931
```

**if real = 1**

```
i stopped at: 1701
error: 9.988463991863827e-09
Ain: 0.6265998215802447
Bin: -0.4220107676504184
```

**if real = 0**

```
i stopped at: 6599
error: 9.964813417717756e-09
Ain: 0.00012989918077312943
Bin: 1.5323536787935905e-07
```

But when **real become negative**, it doesn't work anymore

**if real = -1**

```
i stopped at: 9999
error: 1.00236266444978
Ain: -0.0007688867423695804
Bin: 0.0007688895693352667
```

**if real = -3**

```
i stopped at: 9999
error: 9.021301796298907
Ain: 0.0023093982869384407
Bin: 0.0023093982869377746
```

**if real = -10**

```
i stopped at: 9999
error: 100.23817133864833
Ain: -0.007730146364071466
Bin: -0.007730146364071119
```

also notice that the error is near **real^2**, when the error is negative.

My question: am I doing something wrong? and how can i solve this? 
on everage the value Real can differ from -10 to 10 
thus the range of **real** = [ -10, 10] 
extra info:
**real** is a constant. you might think it in terms of back propagation. **Aout + Bout** should approximate **real** 

kind regards

Comment: What is **real**

Comment: @ab123 - **real** is a constant.  you might think it in terms of back propagation. **Aout + Bout** should approximate **real**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**real** cannot possibly be negative, it's the sum of $2$ positive quantities as $10^{|x|} - 1$ is never less than $0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (this is because $10^x > 1$ for $x > 0$).

So when you do the gradient descent, it tries to achieve the best possible error, which occurs when $x$ is zero. That's why you get $A_{in}$ and $A_{out}$ to be nearly zero after algorithm terminates, and in that case, the error is $(\textbf{rate} - 0 - 0 )^2 = \textbf{rate}^2$ which you already noted.